# how to convert sketch app to android layout

Tags: android, sketchapp

I am trying to **convert the layouts that have been created in sketchapp to android** but somehow i am unable to do so .Please help me out on this one please

Comment: Any updates ? did you find a solution to this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/malkomalko/sketch-android-kit

Well this library may just help. Install this and you are ready to go

#

update: this Lib no longer works.

Comment: but how do i install it

Comment: Not an option anymore in recent versions of Sketch.

Answer (score 1):

Sketch app doesn't have artboard templates for Android devices.

1. Use an artboard size same as the device size.
2. Once finished, select your artboard and click on export on the right corner of your screen to export the artboard into JPG or PNG at a desired resolution.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You are wrong! Didn't you see the "Material Design" section when inserting a new artboard? There is a mobile picture, mobile landscape there!